# Broadcast entry of __m256d

Tags: c, vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx

What is the fastest way to broadcast a single entry of a `__m256d` register to all the elements of an other `__m256d` register using AVX?

For single precision this can be done with a single call to `_mm256_shuffle_ps()`. Moreover, for AVX2 `_mm256d_permute4x64_pd` does seem to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: `_mm256_shuffle_ps` = `VSHUFPS`, which operates within a lane.  You can always use `VSHUFPS` on double-precision data, as long as the shuffle control mask keeps pairs of elements together.

Comment: Is the position of the element to broadcast known at compile time?  If so, that's easy.  Broadcast the high or low 128 to the other 128 with `vinsertf128` or `vperm2f128`, then `vshufpd` to broadcast the element within each lane.  (or `vpermilpd`, but it only has an advantage when the source is in memory.)  But if your source is in memory, you'd just use `vbroadcastpd` if you had to load anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came up with a compact solution but I'm not quite sure if this is the fastest.

```
double pos0[4] = {0,1,2,3};
__m256d a= _mm256_loadu_pd(pos0);

__m256d a02,a13;
a02 = _mm256_shuffle_pd(a,a,0);
__m256d a0 = _mm256_blend_pd(a02, _mm256_permute2f128_pd(a02,a02,1), 0x0C);
__m256d a2 = _mm256_blend_pd(a02, _mm256_permute2f128_pd(a02,a02,1), 0x03);
a13 = _mm256_shuffle_pd(a,a,0x0F);
__m256d a1 = _mm256_blend_pd(a13, _mm256_permute2f128_pd(a13,a13,1), 0x0C);
__m256d a3 = _mm256_blend_pd(a13, _mm256_permute2f128_pd(a13,a13,1), 0x03);
```

This would result in:

```
a0 = {0,0,0,0}
a1 = {1,1,1,1}
a2 = {2,2,2,2}
a3 = {3,3,3,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a `__m256d` register `x4`.  You can broadcast each element to four elements to four `__m256d` registers like this:

```
__m256d t1 = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(x4, x4, 0x0);
__m256d t2 = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(x4, x4, 0x11);
__m256d broad1 = _mm256_permute_pd(t1,0);
__m256d broad2 = _mm256_permute_pd(t1,0xf);
__m256d broad3 = _mm256_permute_pd(t2,0);
__m256d broad4 = _mm256_permute_pd(t2,0xf);
```

For more information see [Is there a more efficient way to broadcast 4 contiguous doubles into 4 YMM registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633241/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-broadcast-4-contiguous-doubles-into-4-ymm-regis)

Answer (score -2):

```
__m256d shuffle(__m256d V, int x, int y, int z, int w) {
    return _mm256_set_pd(V.m256d_f64[x], V.m256d_f64[y], V.m256d_f64[z], V.m256d_f64[w]);
}
```

but it is very very slow